# getting multiple inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I am trying to create a jquery call(Still learning) to pull all the inputs I have on the page when they change, and send them to my php file for parsing, I want to use this to update my DB without a submit button and reloading the page over and over, below is what I currently have

```
    <script>
var data = {};
    $(document).change(function() {
        var $name = $('.test').attr('name');
        var value = $('.test').attr('value');
        data[$name]=value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                $("#legend").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="legend"></div>
<form>
<input type="text" name="hp" class="test">
<input type="text" name="mana" class="test" />
</form>
```

so what I am trying to do above, is use the variables I have set up for all my items with class, so that I don't have to create something to handle each input field, I know I could do it at the end with a submit, im just trying to do it as the person updates text, thanks for your time

Here is a demo(because the php call works here):
http://aardwolfbootcamp.com/lizza/hadtest.php

Comment: You should make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
data = $('form').serialize();
```

Comment: Thank you, i do not know how i missed that in my readings, guess i have more reading to do =/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `serialize()` method , it will encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        $("#legend").html(response);
    }
});
```

or you can use

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: $('.test').serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        $("#legend").html(response);
    }
});
```

[**Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/**](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: this will cause Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'serialize'

Answer (score 0):

You can do the things on change event of form or document, as you are doing.

Example:

```
$("form").on("change", function(){

    console.log($("form").eq(0).serialize());

    $.ajax({
        url : "url.php",
        data : $("form").eq(0).serialize(),
        type : "POST",
        success : function(data){
            // your stuffs here
        }
    });
});
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/5fX2J/)